# Node.js Multer req.file is undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, multer

I try to send image from client (made in react) to server (made in nodeJs) so I can upload it to google cloud storage later.

However - when I receive the call on server req.file is udnefined.
(I do have req.files.file but I use multer and I should have had req.file defined.)

I will post the code:

Front:

```html
          <input
            accept='image/*'
            className='ProfilePage__uploadImage'
            onChange={onFileUploadChange()}
            ref={inputFile}
            name='file'
            id='file'
            type='file'
          />
```

onFileUploadChange function:

```js
const onFileUploadChange = () => (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const image = event?.target?.files?.[0]

    if (image !== undefined) {
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('file', image)
      axios.post('http://localhost:3006/users/uploadProfileImage', data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

Node.js server:

```js
const multer = Multer({
  storage: Multer.MemoryStorage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000, // Maximum file size is 10MB
  }
})

usersRouter.post(
  '/uploadProfileImage',
  multer.single('file'),
  (req, res, next) => {
    // here it crushes - cannot read originalname of undefined.
    const newFileName = req.file.originalname
    const blob = bucket.file(newFileName)
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream()
    blobStream.on('error', (err) => console.log(err))
    blobStream.on('finish', () => {
      console.log('done')
    })
    blobStream.end(req.file.buffer)
  })
```

Comment: req.file.originalname, you have to debug here. File must be in array so you need to use in this way ,,,  req.file[0].originalfile // maybe req.files[0].originalfile ,, you have to debug then you get easily

Comment: event?.target?.files?.[0] // on react side this will be event?.target?.files[0]

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what was the bug all this time...

- in the first place I managed to send the file to GCS using req.files.file

but when I wanted to look at the file it was corrupted.. so I thought I need to do it as the tutorials say.. (in their example it was req.file)
therefore I struggled with it so it be same as examples.

but the issue was not at all related to it.

the issue was that GCL needed me to provide a token for each image.

```js
    const newFileName = req.files.file.name
    const blob = bucket.file(newFileName)
    const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
      metadata: {
        metadata: {
          firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid,
        }
      }
    })
```

now everything works as expected :)

Thanks to everybody who helped.